# Ajax call responds empty list in ScalaJS

Tags: ajax, scala, rest, scala.js

I'm trying out ScalaJS, but I'm stuck on this silly problem. I'm trying to build some kind 'data access layer' that uses a REST-service to fetch some data.

In this service I fetch the data in JSON and convert them into a Seq of a case class and return them. I tested several methods, I'm sure the data is fetched correctly because I've managed to get it to the browser. But when converting it to a Seq, the Seq is always empty.

Any help is welcome...

```scala
 object Results {
  def fetchLatest(): Seq[Result] = {
    var result = Seq.empty[Result]
    get("http://tac-mlavaert.rhcloud.com/results/list/national/after_ss/latest").onComplete {
       case Success(request: dom.XMLHttpRequest) =>
    result = asList(request.responseText).map(ResultFactory.apply).toSeq
    }
    result
  }

  private def asList(response: String): js.Array[js.Dynamic] = js.JSON.parse(response) match {
    case list: js.Array[js.Dynamic] => list
  }
}

object ResultFactory {

  def apply(item: js.Dynamic) = {
    Result(
     item.carNumber.toString,
     item.pilotName.toString,
     item.coPilotName.toString
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an instance of the classical using-an-async-function-as-if-it-were-synchronous issue. Your `fetchLatest()` method first declares an empty sequence, then calls `get`, then returns `result`. But since `get` is asynchronous, `fetchLatest()` returns `result` way before the callback is ever executed, which means that returns the empty sequence that it was when you declared it. (Eventually the callback runs and modifies the variable `result`, but this is not used by anyone anymore at that point.)

So you cannot return directly result in `fetchLatest()`. Once you enter the asynchronous world, you cannot leave it. It means your `fetchLatest()` method must also return a `Future[Seq[Result]]`, which you can obtain by `map`ing the future returned by `get`. That would look like this:

```
  def fetchLatest(): Future[Seq[Result]] = {
    get("http://tac-mlavaert.rhcloud.com/results/list/national/after_ss/latest") map { request =>
      asList(request.responseText).map(ResultFactory.apply).toSeq
    }
  }
```

or equivalently, using a for-comprehension:

```
  def fetchLatest(): Future[Seq[Result]] = {
    for {
      request <- get("http://tac-mlavaert.rhcloud.com/results/list/national/after_ss/latest"
    } yield {
      asList(request.responseText).map(ResultFactory.apply).toSeq
    }
  }
```

Of course, it is then up to the caller of `fetchLatest()` (which you do not show here) to deal with the future, either using `onComplete`, or transforming it further through `map`s and `flatMap`s until, eventually, someone knows what to do with the result.